# Validate numbers, parenthesis and spaces only in jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying and failing hard in validating a phone number within jQuery validation.  All I want is to allow a number like `(01660) 888999`.  Looking around the net I find a million examples but nothing seems to work.  Here is my current effort

```
$.validator.addMethod("phonenumber", function(value) {
  var re = new RegExp("/[\d\s()+-]/g");
  return re.test(value);
  //return value.match("/[\d\s]*$");
}, "Please enter a valid phone number");
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach? Do you get an error message? Do you have some examples of phone numbers it fails to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bergi is correct that the way you are constructing the regular expression is wrong.

Another problem is that you are missing anchors and a `+`:

```
var re = /^[\d\s()+-]+$/;
```

Note though that a regular expression based solution will still allow some inputs that aren't valid phone numbers. You can improve your regular expression in many ways, for example you might want to require that there are at least x digits, for example.

There are many rules for what phone numbers are valid and invalid. It is unlikely you could encode all those rules into a regular expression in a maintainable way, so you could try one of these approaches:

- Find a library that is able to validate phone numbers (but possibly not regular expression based).
- If you need a regular expression, aim for something that is a close approximation to the rules, but doesn't attempt to handle all the special cases. I would suggest trying to write an expression that accepts all valid phone numbers, but doesn't necessarily reject all invalid phone numbers.

You may also want to consider writing test cases for your solution. The tests will also double as a form of documentation of which inputs you wish to accept and reject.

Comment: Yeah, without test cases, some of your users are almost certainly going to be left out in the cold.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either a regex literal **or** a string literal in the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/):

```
var re = /[\d\s()+-]/g;
// or
var re = new RegExp("[\\d\\s()+-]", "g");
```

See also [Creating a Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression).

Apart from that, you would need to use [start- and end-of-string anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to make sure that the regex matches the whole string, not only a part of it, and some [repetition modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) to allow more than one character:

```
var re = /^[\d\s()+-]+$/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach may be:

```
function(value) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(value.replace(/[()\s+-]/g,''));
}
```

and if you want to check for the length of the number too, say it has to be a string with 10 digits:

```
function(value) {
  return /^\d{10}$/.test(value.replace(/[()\s+-]/g,''));
}
```

Comment: That does not allow minus and plus characters